# How to take package .java files into a Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got a copy of a java package, with example implementation. The package is in a structure called com.java.project (folders, containing myriads of .java files) and there's also a few example files (example1.java, example2.java)

The example files have 'import com.java.project' calls in them, that's all well and good. However, I can't seem to work out how to get Eclipse finding the package contents (currently returns "Type not found" for any calls to the project objects.

I've tried placing the com structure in the same level as my example1.java, but that doesn't work. I have read that I need to compile the package into a .jar to get it to work w/Eclipse, but that doesn't seem to want to behave, none of the files compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse you can right click on the Project Explorer and select "New -> Java Project"

Then you can import your java files by right clicking your project, selecting import from file system. If the class file shows an error, open the class file, the class name should have red curly braces, click on the error tick mark and Eclipse will give you an option to move the file to the correct package which in turn creates the folder structure for you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Can you do a check on the build path of your Java project? (Right-click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source tab), and see if the root folder contains the code is properly specified here.

2.Maybe a Project->Clean will help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hii,

Just Create a new project with File -> New menu

you need to open Java Perspective and there you will find a package named "src" you need to copy your "com" directory and paste it at the src folder.

I hope this will work for you.