# How to include Java package source code in an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I´m building a small Java framework in Eclipse (Mars) and Windows (8). My source code files are located somewhere like:

*d:\libs\standard\java*

below such directory exists
a) *com\domain\standard* it contains *com.domain.standard.java* and defines *AClassIn_com_domain_standard*
b) *com\domain\web* it contains *com.domain.web.java* and defines *AClassIn_com_domain_web*, imports com.domain.standard, and defines *SomeClassDerivedFromAClassIn_com_domain_standard*

I need to include such files in the Eclipse project and being able to edit them, or in other words, to be regarded as part of the project. I don´t want to simply copy them over the  project since they will be used and shared among several others.

In the project (DynamiC web Project) I have a source (SomeClass.java) that *import com.domain.web* and defines *SomeClassDerivedFrom_AClassIn_com_domain_web*

I added *d:\libs\standard\java* to the Build Path as a Linked Source and with different Inclussion Patterns
a) If I include *, the files are shown in the Project Explorer without errors
b) If I leave the inclussion pattern empty, the files are also shown but with errors about the package name (does not match...)

In either case, the source code *SomeClass.java* complains that *import com.domain.web* can not be resolved

Even If I intentionally induce syntax errors in any package within *d:\libs\standard\java* they are not flagged which leads to the assumption that are not included in the project

I checked [How to take package .java files into a Eclipse Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675673/how-to-take-package-java-files-into-a-eclipse-project) and some other pages without finding the correct answer.

¿Are my packages names wrong or incorrectly located? (I´m a Java newbie)
¿What I´m missing to do in Eclipse?
Or the obvious ¿Can somebody please give a solution?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The first missconception is that Java packages are a collection of public classes like Oracle packages. They are not. Only a single public class can appear per source file and the *package* directive is used to prompt and assure which package the class belongs to. The second that emerges from the first is the source file name. It should match the class name (including case)

So the steps are
a) rename *com.domain.standard.java* to *AClassIn_com_domain_standard.java*
b) rename *com.domain.web.java* to *AClassIn_com_domain_web.java*
c) remove the import directive from *AClassIn_com_domain_web.java*. It no longer will be required (it doesn´t hurt either)
d) Create a new source under *com\domain\web* named *SomeClassDerivedFromAClassIn_com_domain_standard.java*
e) Add *d:\libs\standard\java* to the Build Path as a Linked Source leaving the Import Pattern empty

*SomeClassDerivedFrom_AClassIn_com_domain_web.java* correctly imports any package and source code errors are flagged